# Stokes equations and change of variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations, divergence-operator, change-of-variable, linear-pde

Let $\Omega$ be domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Phi : \Omega \to \Phi(\Omega)$ a deformation. Consider the Stokes equations written in the deformed configuration

\begin{align}
- 2\mu \operatorname{div}(D(u)) + \nabla p &= f, \quad \text{in } \Phi(\Omega) \\
\operatorname{div}(u) &= 0, \quad \text{in } \Phi(\Omega) \\
\end{align}

where $u$ is the velocity of the fluid, $p$ the pressure, $\mu>0$ is the constant viscosity, $f$ is an external force and $D$ is the operator defined by

$$
D(u) = \frac{1}{2} (\nabla u + \nabla u^T).
$$

How can the Stokes equations be written in the domain $\Omega$ using a change of variable ?

Comment: You can get proper formatting for operators like $\operatorname{div}$ using e.g. `\operatorname{div}`.

Comment: I'm confused, if $\operatorname{div} = 0$ in the deformed configuration, then doesn't the first equation reduce to $\nabla p = f$ as it is also in the same deformed configuration?

Comment: I forgot the symetric gradient operator in the divergence operator. I edited the question.

Comment: Now asked on MathOverflow: [Change of variable for the Stokes equations](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308543).